# working with a folder outside the webservice folder

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-services

I have a asp.net webservice running in windows server 2003, i want it read/write to other folder that is in other machine, i have granted to this folder full acess to Network Service, IIS_user, IIS_IWAM accounts but the process fail, this is the error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\machineIp\ServerDataStore\Prueba\Editados' is denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825709/c-3-5-asp-net-file-io-issue-unauthorizedaccessexception-to-file-on-network-shar/825751#825751)